# Как в content_scripts дождаться пока придет ответ на POST запрос выполняемый в background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

У меня есть `content_script` который посылает в `background.js` сообщение:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({type: 'test', text: my_text}, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

А в `background.js` получает это сообщение и выполняет POST запрос к определенному ресурсу.

Мне нужно дождаться ответа от ресурса, и этот ответ передать в `content_script` который после того как придет этот ответ - продолжить работать с ним уже сам.

Вот код `background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if ( request.type == "test" ) {
            let text = request.text;

            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://example.com");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onload = function () {
                sendResponse( this.responseText );
            }
            xhr.send('text='+text);
        }
    }
);
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: а тем же макаром назад `sendMessage` нельзя?

Comment: @NikitaUmnov а как слушать его?

Comment: видимо `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener`. Извини, сам дел с этим не имел, но по мануала так

Comment: @NikitaUmnov нет, так не работает